# Updating SDK to 2.17.0 - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk

I want to update my SDK version to 2.17.0 to use the super constructor but ran into this error. I have update dart and Flutter put can not update the pubspect.yaml file. I am using Visual Studio Code[image]

Comment: just do flutter upgrade

Answer (score 0):

You want at least 2.17.0. You actually are higher than that, at 2.18.0. You specified that you want exactly 2.17.0. I recommend to change it to

```
sdk: ">=2.17.0 <3.0.0"
```

This way any version between 2.17.0 and 3.0.0 is allowed. 3.0.0 doesn't exist yet but it's good practice to add this limitation in case 3.0.0 is released, which might break things